# Extract table from multi nested JSON in R

Tags: r, json

I have a big json file in which there are a number of surveys with data about the results. The file is quite complicated, but I managed to generate table using nested loops. The solution is obviously time consuming and I'm sure there are better ways of doing that with purrrr or dt. Unfortunately I can't share the data, so I attach a sample that works with the loop:

```
{
  "research": {
    "re.id": "id"
  },
  "surveys": [
    {
      "id": "10017",
      "participant": "31804190",
      "answers": [
        {
          "item": "685022",
          "results": [
            {
              "items": "o",
              "value": 2
            },
            {
              "items": "pb",
              "value": 3
            },
            {
              "items": "r",
              "value": 2
            },
            {
              "items": "s",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "t",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "w",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "z",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "f",
              "value": 2
            },
            {
              "items": "e",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "items": "l",
              "value": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "item": "90118",
          "results": [
            {
              "items": "o",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "pb",
              "value": 3
            },
            {
              "items": "r",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "items": "s",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "t",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "w",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "z",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "f",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "items": "e",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "items": "l",
              "value": 0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "item": "30094",
          "results": [
            {
              "items": "o",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "pb",
              "value": 2
            },
            {
              "items": "r",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "s",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "items": "t",
              "value": 2
            },
            {
              "items": "w",
              "value": 1
            },
            {
              "items": "z",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "f",
              "value": 0
            },
            {
              "items": "e",
              "value": -3
            },
            {
              "items": "l",
              "value": 3
}]}]}]}
```

Notice that each of 357 surveys consist of 13 data points and the last one is a list of 25 answers with 10 results. The nested loop goes through all surveys, excluding those unfinished and then another loop goes through all answers for each survey and next loop goes through all results for each answer within each survey. Moreover, the results are given in random order so they need to be sorted, that happens at the end of the nested loop.

Here is the sample of that JSON: https://jsonblob.com/2bffde45-d8c0-11e9-9ec2-759b3e404be9

```
library(rjson)

survey.report <- fromJSON(file = "sample.json")
values.df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 13, nrow = 0))
listofitems <- list() 

for (a in 1:length(surveytoll[["surveys"]])) {
  if (length(surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["answers"]]) == 0) {
    listofitems[i] <- 0
    i <- i + 1
  } else {
    for (o in 1:length(surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["answers"]])) {
      surveyid <- surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["answers"]][[o]][["item"]]
      i <- i + 1
      listofitems[i] <- surveyid 
      for (w in 1:length(surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["answers"]][[o]][["results"]])) {
        answers <- surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["answers"]][[o]][["results"]]
      } 
      survey = surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["id"]]
      participant = surveytoll[["surveys"]][[a]][["participant"]]

      list.items <- list()
      list.values <- list()
      list.items <- sapply(answers, function(x) x[[1]])
      list.values <- sapply(answers, function(x) x[[2]])
      lwtt <- t(t(list.values)) 
      lpbtt <- t(t(list.items))
      lplw <- cbind.data.frame(lpbtt,lwtt)
      lplw$lwtt <- as.character(lplw$lwtt)
      lplw$lpbtt <- as.character(lplw$lpbtt)
      lplw[order(lplw$lpbtt),]
      value <- t(lplw$lwtt) 
      values.row <- cbind(survey,participant,listofitems[i],value)
      values.df <- rbind.data.frame(values.df,values.row) 
    }
  }
}

values.df
```

The loop generates data frame with 13 columns: survey id, participant, item and 10 results. The sample has only 3 rows:

```
  survey participant     V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 V11 V12 V13
1  10017    31804190 685022  2  3  2  0  0  0   0   2   1   0
2  10017    31804190  90118  0  3  1  0  0  0   0   1   1   0
3  10017    31804190  30094  0  2  0  1  2  1   0   0  -3   3
```

The problem is that the main json is really big (10GB), so the loop will take weeks ;).

Comment: I think you're missing the `str` / `dput` line. Please edit/provide so that this is reproducible for others.

Comment: Thank you, I've updated the code and the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could leverage the relatively new `unnest_wider` and `unnest_longer` functions from `tidyr` (within the `tidyverse`) -- see [this vignette on "rectangling: for more information on extracting information from deeply nested structures](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/rectangle.html)

```
library(tidyverse)

json <- jsonlite::fromJSON('sample.json', simplifyVector = FALSE)

surveys <- tibble(survey = json$surveys)

surveys %>%
    unnest_wider(survey) %>%
    unnest_longer(answers) %>%
    unnest_wider(answers) %>%
    unnest_longer(results) %>%
    unnest_wider(results) %>%
    pivot_wider(
        names_from = items,
        values_from = value
    )

# # A tibble: 3 x 13
#   id    participant item       o    pb     r     s     t     w     z     f     e     l
#   <chr> <chr>       <chr>  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1 10017 31804190    685022     2     3     2     0     0     0     0     2     1     0
# 2 10017 31804190    90118      0     3     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0
# 3 10017 31804190    30094      0     2     0     1     2     1     0     0    -3     3
```

Comment: Works well with the sample. However, if I have more surveys in original data it stucks:

surveys <- tibble(survey = json$surveys)
surveys <- unnest_wider(surveys,survey)
surveys <- unnest_longer(surveys,answers)
surveys <- unnest_wider(surveys,answers)
surveys <- unnest_longer(surveys,results)
surveys <- unnest_wider(surveys,results,names_repair = "check_unique")
pivot_wider(surveys,
  names_from = items,
  values_from = value 
  )

Comment: ERROR: Column name `...1` must not be duplicated.
Use .name_repair to specify repair.
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace